# Java API for filter_path in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I need to reduce the response size of elastic search query, So I found one way to use Response Filtering through filter_path parameter in URL.

```
GET testindex-2016.04.14/_search?filter_path=aggregations.testAggs.buckets
```

Below is the link: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/common-options.html#_response_filtering

But I couldn't find any way to implement response filtering in Java API,
While googling, I have also seen one `FilterPath.java` class in elastic search, but I couldn't find any example of it. Even I am not sure whether this class can be used for this purpose or not.

Please suggest me any way to implement response filtering in Java. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want some fields in the response you should specify them in your query like this:

```
 myquery = {
    "_source": {
        "includes": ["user.screen_name", "entities.user_mentions.screen_name"]},
    "query": {
        "bool": {....
```

You can also use "exclude".

Here is the documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html